# Wordpress ЧПУ get параметра

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, get, чпу

есть страница stranicza-profilya, я вывожу на ней get параметр site.com/stranicza-profilya/?id=field845604
Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу стилизовать url в виде site.com/stranicza-profilya/field845604/

Перепробовал очень много вариантов в function.php

```
    function rewrite_rules() {
    // Теги
    add_rewrite_tag( '%id%', '([^&]+)', 'id=' );

    // Правило перезаписи
    add_rewrite_rule( '^stranicza-profilya/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=13&id=$matches[1]', 'top' );

    // Скажем WP, что есть новые параметры запроса
    add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = 'id';
        return $vars;
    } );
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rules' );
```

К сожалению не срабатывает, даже когда я пересохраняю ЧПУ.
Напрямую в htaccess вписывать не хочу, так как wp автоматически его создает и есть вероятность что в будущем он может затереть его.
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Проверил Ваш код, он работает.

Чтобы правило начало работать, нужно обновить (сбросить) правила в БД. Для этого нужно вызвать функцию flush_rules(). Или просто зайти в Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки там автоматически сработает flush_rules().

Comment: Подскажите как мне сделать редирект при ссылке site.com/stranicza-profilya/?id=field845604  на site.com/stranicza-profilya/field845604/

Comment: Используйте wp_redirect() https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_redirect

Comment: Все таки мне кажется что мой код не совсем рабочий, url он заменяет как надо, но wordpress определяет этот url как 404 ошибку, add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
 if( is_page(13) ){
  $variable_to_send =  get_query_var('id');
  if(get_query_var('id')) {
  wp_redirect( get_page_link(13) .$variable_to_send );
  exit;
  }
 }
} );

Comment: Возможно где то ошибка. Но я его воспроизвел у себя на тестовой сборке, и он отработал. Вернул мне страницу stranicza-profilya с query_var 'id'. Попробуйте сделать дебаг запроса с помощью хук-фильтра request или parse_request

Comment: Ошибок нет, мне кажется для WP это теперь новая страница site.com/stranicza-profilya/field845604/ и в базе страниц он ее не нашел, вот он и выдает 404 ошибку, но как мне сделать чтобы он возвращал меня на страницу site.com/stranicza-profilya/ и в url подставлял get параметр

Comment: А у вас физически создана данная страница? Я имею в виду в админке вы создавали эту страницу?

Comment: страница site.com/stranicza-profilya/ - есть, но страницы site.com/stranicza-profilya/field845604/ - данной страницы нет

Comment: site.com/stranicza-profilya/  Я про нее и спрашивал. Еще раз попробуйте зайти Настройки -> Постоянные и нажмите Сохранить изменения.

Comment: Хорошо, теперь ошибки 404 нет, но он перекидывает меня на главную страницу, почему не понимаю пока

Comment: Верните код в исходное состояние (без редиректов), Сделайте снова Сохранение настроек. И попробуйте открыть в новой вкладке в режиме инкогнито, потому что браузер мог закешировать ваш редирект.

Comment: редирект убрал, зашел в ЧПУ чтобы сохранить настройки, запустил в инкогнито чтобы избежать кеширования. http://prntscr.com/vxjfbx   и http://prntscr.com/vxjikx . Все равно перебрасывает на главную, post_id правильный

Comment: Прощу прощения, кажется в этом и была ошибка< я в правиле перезаписи использовал не page_id а post_id )) ужас, какой не внимательный! Спасибо Вам большое, как я могу вас отблагодарить?